# Can't connect Sequelize to MySQL docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am currently learning how to use Sequilize with GraphQL. I was following a tutorial from Youtube.

I created a docker container with a `mysql:5.7.20` image on port `7999`. I have done the basic Sequelize setup using sequelize-cli. I am able to connect to my database through DBeave. But when I run `sequelize db:migrate`,  it returns `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1:7999`.

Docker commands I used to create the container:

```sh
docker run \
  -p 0.0.0.0:7999:3306 \
  --name gsd-db \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
  -e MYSQL_USER=gsd-dev \
  -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=gsd \
  -d mysql:5.7.20
```

Development environment in the config.json file

```
"development": {
    "username": "gsd-dev",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "gsd",
    "host": "127.0.0.1:7999",
    "dialect": "mysql"
}
```

Comment: Try using `-p 127.0.0.1:7999:3306`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the same problem I meet, I solved it by setting access rights of node. you can try:

```sh
docker exec -it {mysqlid} sh

mysql -uroot -p

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION; 

mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

# Update incryption rules

mysql>ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;

# update root password

mysql>ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'abc123456'; 

mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```